# Adding data to crosstable created by EF with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

It is my first a many-to-many relation consisting of **Team**, **User** and **TeamUser** objects. In **TeamController** I mapped **TeamForCreationDto** to **Team**, but ICollection Members was empty. Some bug in CreateMap?
Q1: How it should be combined to fill all property and tables by EF? Now I have "for" loop and there created/added TeamUser.
Q2: If I must fill both property AdminId and Admin?
A2: No, after adding Admin, property AdminId in DB thanks EF will find value automatically.

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AdminId { get; set; }
    public User Admin { get; set; }
    //public int[] MembersId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeamUser> Members { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> TeamsAsAdmin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TeamUser> TeamsAsMember { get; set; }
}
public class TeamUser
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Relations between tables in **ModelBuilder**

```
builder.Entity<Team>()
    .HasOne(t => t.Admin)
    .WithMany(u => u.TeamsAsAdmin)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<TeamUser>()
    .HasKey(tu => new { tu.TeamId, tu.UserId });

builder.Entity<TeamUser>()
    .HasOne(tu => tu.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.TeamsAsMember)
    .HasForeignKey(tu => tu.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.Entity<TeamUser>()
    .HasOne(tu => tu.Team)
    .WithMany(t => t.Members)
    .HasForeignKey(tu => tu.TeamId);
```

My **CreateMap** in **AutoMapperProfiles()**

```
CreateMap<TeamForCreationDto, Team>().ReverseMap().ForMember(u => u.MembersId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Members));
```

My **TeamController.cs**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int userId, TeamForCreationDto teamForCreationDto)
    {

        if (await _repoTeams.TeamExists(teamForCreationDto.Name))
            return BadRequest("A team with this name already exists!");
        var mappedTeam = _mapper.Map<Team>(teamForCreationDto);
        //mappedTeam.AdminId = userId;
        mappedTeam.Admin = await _repoUsers.GetUser(userId);
        _repoTeams.Add(mappedTeam);
        for (int i = 0; i < teamForCreationDto.MembersId.Length; i++)
        {
            TeamUser tm = new TeamUser();
            tm.Team = mappedTeam;
            tm.User = await _repoUsers.GetUser(teamForCreationDto.MembersId[i]);
            _repoTeams.Add(tm);
        }
        await _repoTeams.SaveAll();
    }
```

**TeamForCreationDto.cs**

```
public class TeamForCreationDto
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public int[] MembersId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn `TeamForCreationDto ` look like? And what's the role of the commented code in `Team`?

Comment: Added TeamForCreationDto from front I want to receive only ID members. The commented line in Team is answer on my second question - I don't need declared AdminId to fill dbcontent - maybe I think badly?

Comment: It's much simpler to use a DTO class for `TeamUser` as well. `TeamForCreationDto` could have a computed property that only returns their IDs.